Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin in Flutter project
I have a Flutter project. I am currently working on it in Android Studio and building to Android for testing.
Yesterday, my project was working fine. This morning, it will not compile. The error message says "Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin". I did that, and it still will not compile. Now it says, "Kotlin: Unsupported version of com.android.tools.build:gradle plugin: version 4.2.2 or higher should be used with kotlin-android plugin".
I have the latest version of all the software as far as I can tell. Android studio, all of its plugins, and Flutter itself.
This message is a summary. I actually spent about three hours trying different things to resolve the problem. I need help.
I chose Flutter for the promise that it would save me time compared to writing multiple apps, but so far I've spent more time fixing Flutter problems than I have writing my actual program. I do not think I'll use it again.
Frank

You need to change the kotlin version in your android root project, go to projectName/android/build.gradle
Latest Kotlin version here
Also change your gradle wrapper in the gradle-wrapper.properties
